# split() but keep delimiter

Tags: perl, split

```
 my $string1 = "Hi. My name is Vlad. It is snowy outside.";

 my @array = split('.' $string1); ##essentially I want this, but I want the period to be kept
```

I want to split this string at the `.`, but I want to keep the period. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the Perl split function, but keeping certain delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237274/using-the-perl-split-function-but-keeping-certain-delimiters)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use lookbehind to do this:

```
split(/(?<=\.)/, $string)
```

The regex matches an empty string that follows a period.

If you want to remove the whitespace between the sentences at the same time, you can change it to:

```
split(/(?<=\.)\s*/, $string)
```

Positive and negative lookbehind is explained [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: It works exactly how it should thank you. Would you mind explaining exactly what is happening?

Comment: Added a link to regular-expressions.info

Comment: with a word like 'foo' this worked for me: split(/(?=foo)/, $string)

Comment: @basin That's true, lookbehinds have to have a fixed length.

Comment: More efficient versions: `split /\.\K/` and `split /\.\K\s*/`

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind the periods being split into their own elements in the array, you can use parentheses to tell split to keep them:

```
my @array = split(/(\.)/, $string);
```

Comment: I suppose I could work with that, but I would prefer to have them attached to the sentence so that each array element is essentially a sentence.

Comment: It sounds like a lookbehind or lookahead assertion problem, which I'm not comfortable with.