# Capture in split

Tags: regex, perl, split

I do this:

```
my @words =split(/[~,;#&=\.\s\|\(\)\+\-\?\:]+/,$string);
my @processed_words = ();
foreach (@words)  {push(@processed_words,process_word($_));}
```

Could someone suggest an easy way to compose `$string` back after processing while keeping the unprocessed parts intact?
Or is `split` not the way to go here?

Comment: You mean you want to re-combine `@processed_words` with the original delimiters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the delimiters in the regexp in a capture group, then `split` will include the delimiters in its result -- it will alternate between words and delimiters. You can then push the unprocessed delimiters and the processed words onto the result array.

```
my @words =split(/([~,;#&=\.\s\|\(\)\+\-\?\:]+)/,$string);
my @processed_words = ();
foreach (@words)  {
    if (/[~,;#&=\.\s\|\(\)\+\-\?\:]/) { // delimiter, just copy it
        push(@processed_words, $_)
    } else { // process the word
        push(@processed_words,process_word($_));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a capture group around your delimiter to keep the delimiter in the result array. Then use a for loop and check if the index is odd or even, example *(that splits on non-word characters and makes word characters uppercase)*:

```
echo 'a"b@c%d.e^f$g' | perl -ne '@a=split(/(\W+)/);for($i=0;$i<@a;++$i){ print $i%2 ? @a[$i] : uc@a[$i];}'
```

(Where `$i%2` checks if the index `$i` is odd or even).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by "compose $string back after splitting", but maybe something like:

```
my $composed = join(" ", map { process_word($_) } @words);
```

...would do the trick?

Comment: In that case, this is a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907772/split-but-keep-delimiter